# calculate difference in counts in 2 columns for corresponding values in other column

Tags: google-sheets

I have 4 columns with values (A and C are products that mostly overlap, B and D are counts. What I'd like to do is for the values that occur in both A and C calculate the difference between B and D, and put the result in E and F.

So for example 5028421938592 count is 6 in column B and count is 2 in column D. 
The result would be then be in column E: 5028421938592 and column F: 4

```
5028421928548   3       5028421928548   1
5028421938592   6       3259190205192   7
5028421997131   1       5028421938592   2
5028421995748   4       5028421995748   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in E1:

```
=unique(query({A:B;C:D},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col1"))
```

and in F1 and copied down to suit:

```
=iferror(vlookup(E1,A:B,2,0),0)-iferror(vlookup(E1,C:D,2,0),0)
```